# how to filter out rows with max values of only some of the groups using tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with two columns of interest that looks like this:

```
V1   V2
1    10
1    56
1    72
1    37
2    59
2    29
2    105
2    93    
3    53
3    40
3    84
3     3
4    62
4    34
4    18
4    42
5    38
5    92
5    79
5    25
```

I would like to use tidyverse to remove the rows that contains the respective max value in V2 for each of the groups V1 = 2 and V1 = 5.

Thus, for the dataframe above, I would like to get the output:

```
V1   V2
1    10
1    56
1    72
1    37
2    59
2    29
2    93
3    53
3    40
3    84
3     3
4    62
4    34
4    18
4    42
5    38
5    79
5    25
```

Here is code to make the dataframe:

`df = data.frame(V1= rep(1:5, each=4), V2 = sample(1:100,20))`

Answer (score 1):

Do a group by `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(V1) %>% 
   filter(!(V2 == max(V2) & V1 %in% c(2, 5))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 18 × 2
      V1    V2
   <int> <int>
 1     1    10
 2     1    56
 3     1    72
 4     1    37
 5     2    59
 6     2    29
 7     2    93
 8     3    53
 9     3    40
10     3    84
11     3     3
12     4    62
13     4    34
14     4    18
15     4    42
16     5    38
17     5    79
18     5    25
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .(I = .I[!(.GRP %in% c(2, 5) & V2 == max(V2))]), V1]$I]
```

---

Or in `base R` with `ave`

```
subset(df, !(V1 %in% c(2, 5) & V2 ==ave(V2, V1, FUN = max)))
   V1 V2
1   1 10
2   1 56
3   1 72
4   1 37
5   2 59
6   2 29
8   2 93
9   3 53
10  3 40
11  3 84
12  3  3
13  4 62
14  4 34
15  4 18
16  4 42
17  5 38
19  5 79
20  5 25
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), V2 = c(10L, 56L, 72L, 
37L, 59L, 29L, 105L, 93L, 53L, 40L, 84L, 3L, 62L, 34L, 18L, 42L, 
38L, 92L, 79L, 25L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: This removes the max for each of the groups of V1,  but I only want it for specific groups of V1 and not others.

Comment: @ag14 It is a bit strange that your updated comment that this works got removed by someone leaving the initial comment as it is.

Comment: Indeed. I will add again. This works after the updates made to it to look for only specific groups of V1